# Script-Block parsing issues

Tags: powershell

I am running some code that is read from an encrypted file and converted into a ScriptBlock. The code will be a full complex script, but for simplicity let's assume it is the following:

```
"$(date) Agent started." | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\TMP\test_agent.log' -Append
while($true) {
    '$(date) Will check back in 30 seconds...' | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\TMP\test_agent.log' -Append
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
```

Below is the simple code that launches it, and it works just fine (the `$sStr` variable contains the above script as a string):

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $sb = $executioncontext.invokecommand.NewScriptBlock($args[0])
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb
} -ArgumentList $sStr | Wait-Job -Timeout 1 | Receive-Job
```

Again, this works fine. However, I need this to run as a new PowerShell process. But when I try the below the ScriptBlock is not parsed properly and I get errors. Here is the modified launcher:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $sb = $executioncontext.invokecommand.NewScriptBlock($args[0])
    powershell "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb"
} -ArgumentList $sStr | Wait-Job -Timeout 1 | Receive-Job
```

How to start a new powershell process (and kill the parent) so that the ScriptBlock is correctly parsed and executed?
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text of the errors that you are receiving. This is needed if you wish useful advice.

Comment: It is also a good idea to take the [Tour] and read the [ask] page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could solve your problem with a PowerShell background job, which can be created via [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1). `Start-Job` also has a `-ScriptBlock` parameter. 
[Example 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Job?view=powershell-5.1) of `Get-Job` shows you how to check if the job is already completed, and how you can retrieve the results of the job.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out to be simple. `Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb` executes without problems. Though I still don't understand why the script block is being parsed differently when used as a parameter to powershell.